# What determines whether or not I can use Pocket for a page on Kobo Reader?

Tags: kobo, website, pocket

I recently discovered that I could use Pocket to wirelessly send webpages I wanted to read onto my kobo reader.
It is great, because it reformats them nicely into something I can adjust the font-size on and without nav-bars etc.

I've mostly used this for reading short stores. Eg from [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/2016/09/28/the-city-born-great/)
This works fine.

Sometimes I want to read blog posts. Eg [Charles Stross's blog](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2017/03/the-internet-of-decay.html).
This does not. It just does not show up at all on the reader.
But other blogs, eg [my own](http://white.ucc.asn.au/2017/05/04/Plain-Functions-that-Just-Work-with-TensorFlow.jl.html) do work.

I have workout, by going to the [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/a/queue/grid/) web interface, that the ones that are not working on my reader, are ones that are saved in "*web only view*".
Which means rather than giving me a reformatted article, 
it just links to the page.
And Kobo reader does not display these kinds of links.

What I don't understand is why somethings save properly and others become "*web only views*"?

- How can I know which has occurred when I save it?

  - particularly if I save it from the Kobo's own webbrowser.
  - Firefox is also worth knowing.
- Why does it occur, what kinda sites should I not waste time on?
- Can I make Kobo display these as links to open in its webbrowser?